# Django migration stuck

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-south

I have a new field to add to my db.  So I say

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

which correctly creates `kernel/migrations/0003_auto_20150726_1911.py`.  I inspect the contents and all looks good.

I say

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and I am less happy. The file `kernel/migrations/0002_auto_20150707_1459.py`, which adds field `date_of_birth` to table `userprofile`, fails.  Even though I'm pretty sure that migration is applied.  And so migration 0003 is never applied.

This is production. :(
I'm not at all sure what to do in order to apply 0003 and not hose django.  Suggestions?

The rest of this is supporting docs:

### The migrations

```
╭╴ (master=) [virt]╶╮
╰ [T] django@beta13:migrations $ cat 0002_auto_20150707_1459.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('kernel', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='userprofile',
    name='date_of_birth',
    field=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True),
    ),
]
╭╴ (master=) [virt]╶╮
╰ [T] django@beta13:migrations $ cat 0003_auto_20150726_1911.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ('kernel', '0002_auto_20150707_1459'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
    model_name='trippending',
    name='requesting_user',
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, related_name='trippending_requesting', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
    model_name='userprofile',
    name='can_see_pending_trips',
    field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
    ),
]
╭╴ (master=) [virt]╶╮
╰ [T] django@beta13:migrations $
```

### The error

(The site runs in French, but I think the error is clear anyway.)

```
╭╴ (master %=) [virt]╶╮
╰ [T] django@beta13:django $ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages, admindocs
  Apply all migrations: admin, sessions, custom_user, auth, kernel, contenttypes, registration, sites
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying kernel.0002_auto_20150707_1459...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 484, in alter_field
old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 571, in _alter_field
old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1322, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1317, in get_prep_value
return self.to_python(value)
  File "/src/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1287, in to_python
params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["Le format de date de la valeur «\xa0\xa0» n'est pas valide. Le format correct est AAAA-MM-JJ."]
╭╴ (master %=) [virt]╶╮
╰ 1,[T] django@beta13:django $
```

### The data

I checked with postgres, expecting to find something amiss.  But all looks fine.

```
mydb=# select date_of_birth from kernel_userprofile;
 date_of_birth 
---------------
 2018-10-23
 1972-05-31
 1978-10-21
 2008-12-29
 1967-08-26
 2015-07-26
(6 rows)

mydb=#
```

Comment: Did some body mess around with the migrations table? Usually this happens when the migrations row for 0002 migration was removed from db, can you check that? Also I think the stack trace is not complete, can you complete it to assist further.

Comment: I don't think anyone has mucked with it.  How do I check the migrations table?  I don't see a likely candiate in postgres.

Comment: The stack trace runs from my prompt to my next prompt.  I'm pretty sure all the intervening lines are present.  What seems to be missing?

Comment: Usually it is django_migrations if you are using Django 1.7 and not south.

Comment: 3;"auth";"0001_initial";"2015-07-22 10:18:57.612555+05:30" Data for migrations in tables will look like this. Based on the last migration the next migration will be picked.

Comment: Ah, sure enough !  I'm not sure how this happened, but it is so.  Saying "select * from django_migrations where app='kernel';" -> one row, "11 | kernel | 0001_initial | 2015-07-07 10:53:16.14909+02".  (1 row)

    locomobase=#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84317/discussion-between-jma-and-kumar).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the community, the issue was `django_migrations` table was not updated with `0002_auto_20150707_1459` even though the migration was actually applied on `table` as mentioned in the post.

The solution was to insert a new row in `django_migrations` table with data like below so migration `0002` was skipped.

```
INSERT INTO DJANGO_MGRATIONS ('app', 'name', 'applied') VALUES ('appname', '0002_auto_20150707_1459', '2015-07-07 00:00')
```

> Skipping migration must be done with extreme caution, hence check all details before skipping.

Answer (score 3):

Same trouble happend, but without any logs

1. At first I determined what app was a problem, by running

```
python manage.py migrate app_name
```

for every `django` app

2. after that I check migrations for app by running

```
python manage.py showmigrations app_name
```

3. And marked first uncompleted migration as completed by running

```
python manage.py migrate --fake app_name migration_name
```

[※ about fake](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake)

And that was a solution in my case

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this post: I just helped a coworker debug a similar problem (same error message), and in this case the source of the problem was trying to give the DateField a default value of `u""` (which is of course invalid for a date) instead of `None`.

Actually part of the fun was that the previous migration (which created the model) already had this wrong default but still ran seamlessly, the error only appearing when trying to alter the field in any way.

The fix required editing the *previous* migration to set the sane default value, since Django uses the previous migration's schema description to get the previous default value.