# Invalid Default value for entry that doesnt exist

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

I am looking at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) example in the Django docs to add a field to my `CustomUser` which has just a few choices.

I added this

```py
    class StringInstrument(models.TextChoices):
        VIOLIN = 'VIO', _('Viool')
        ALT_VIOLIN = 'AVI', _('Alt Viool')
        CELLO = 'CEL', _('Cello')
        DOUBLE_BASS = 'CON', _('Contrabas')
        OTHER = 'OTH', _('Anders')

    working_on = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=StringInstrument.choices,
        default=StringInstrument.OTHER
    )
```

which gave me the following traceback when migrating:

```
  File "...\mysite\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\schema.py", line 105, in add_field
    super().add_field(model, field)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 641, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 192, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "...\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'working_on'")
```

The migrations:

```py
# 0004_customuser_working_on.py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('polls', '0003_alter_customuser_phone'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='working_on',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('VIO', 'viool'), ('AVI', 'altviool'), ('CEL', 'cello'), ('CBA', 'contrabas'), ('N_A', 'nothing')], default='nothing', max_length=3),
        ),
    ]

# ----------------------------------------------- #

# 0005_alter_customuser_working_on.py (made a mistake where the default was indeed wrong, but definitely should be fixed with this)
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('polls', '0004_customuser_working_on'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='working_on',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('VIO', 'Viool'), ('AVI', 'Alt Viool'), ('CEL', 'Cello'), ('CON', 'Contrabas'), ('OTH', 'Anders')], default='OTH', max_length=3),
        ),
    ]
```

I don't see how the the default is invalid. When directly copy pasting in the example, creating migrations and migrating I still get the same error, which is especially weird as the whole column shouldn't even exist anymore:

```py
# 0006_remove_customuser_working_on_and_more.py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('polls', '0005_alter_customuser_working_on'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='working_on',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='year_in_school',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('FR', 'Freshman'), ('SO', 'Sophomore'), ('JR', 'Junior'), ('SR', 'Senior'), ('GR', 'Graduate')], default='FR', max_length=2),
        ),
    ]
```

Versions:

- mysqlclient==2.1.0
- Django==4.0.3
- Python 3.9.8

I have flushed the database as well

**EDIT**

It appears my migrations were somehow stuck. When calling `py manage.py migrate` it always did migration 0004 and not the newer ones. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640068/django-migration-stuck) post helped me fix it.

Comment: your model field default value should be `default='N_A'`

Comment: in `# 0004_customuser_working_on.py`, your default is `'nothing'`, hence it gets stuck there.

Comment: I know that's why I edited it with `0005_alter_customuser_working_on.py`

Comment: this has to be some kind of django or mysql bug I *really* don't see what I am doing wrong here